# Reverse geocoding in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Iam working for a web project. In that i will get the coordinates latitude and longitude. Now i has to get the location details like city and street. How can i get it using reverse geocoding

Comment: try using Google Maps javascript API

Comment: Please can you provide a piece of code

Comment: bear in mind that not all lat/long co-ords map to a street address. ;-)

Comment: i think this basicly a dipclate question of stackoverflow.com/questions/7738388/how-to-reverse-geocoding

Comment: but i want the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

Reverse geocoding can be accomplished using Google Maps Javascript API.

Google provides a nice code example [here](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding)

Comment: Google Maps API isnt free any more, since jan12.